# Creating decision boundry

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this circle dataset with 3 Variables (V1,V2 and V3), where V1 are random points on x-axis and V2 on y-axis. And V3 is a classifier if the point is a circle or not.

Circle equation x^2 + y^2

I am trying to plot a decision boundary around the circle using models like decision tree, polynomial logistic regression and Naïve Bayes theorem with the help of ggplot2, but I am unable to do that.

This is the link to data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZEuwrBN6ilKIDVVT8WGH1SRLTi3diL9Q/view?usp=sharing

Below is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
circle = read.csv("unknown.arff", header=FALSE, comment.char = "@")

######################## MODEL 1: Decision Tree
#Loading the decision tree library
library(rpart)

#Fitting the decision tree model
Circle_tree = rpart(V3 ~V1+V2, data=circle)

# Predicting the probability of having a circle
tree_p = predict(Circle_tree, circle)

#Making 0.5 or more as a cutoff rate for having circle 
Tree = ifelse(tree_p >= 0.5, 1, 0)

#ploting the expected output as per Decision tree
ggplot(circle, aes(x = V1, y =V2, color = Tree)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2) + 
  ggtitle("Decision Tree")


######################## MODEL 2: Logistics Regression with Polynomial terms
#Fitting the Logistics Regression
glm.fit = glm(V3~V2+V1+ I(V1^2)+ I(V2^2), family = "binomial", data = circle)

# Predicting the probability of having a circle
p =predict(glm.fit, circle, type = "response")

#Making 0.5 or more as a cutoff rate for having circle 
Logistic_poly = ifelse(p >= 0.5, 1, 0)

#ploting the expected output as per logistics regression with polynomial terms
ggplot(circle, aes(x = V1, y =V2, color = Logistic_poly)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  ggtitle("Logistics Regression with Polynomial Terms")



######################## MODEL 3: Naive Bayes Classifier
# Loading the library
library(e1071)

#Fitting the naive bayes classifier
circle_nb = naiveBayes(V3 ~V1+V2, data=circle)


# Predicting the probability of having a circle
nb_p = predict(circle_nb, circle, type = "raw")

#Making 0.5 or more as a cutoff rate for having circle 
Naive_Bayes = ifelse(nb_p >= 0.5, 1, 0)

#ploting the expected output as per Naive Bayes Classifier
ggplot(circle, aes(x = V1, y =V2, color = Naive_Bayes[,2])) + 
  geom_point(size = 2) + 
  ggtitle("Naive Bayes Classifier")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the subset of points which lie on the convex hull of the set of points specified with `grDevices::chull` and draw the boarder with `geom_polygon()`.
(I used decision tree model as an example).
When you gives `grDevices::chull` x and y coordinates, it returns indices of the points on the convex hull in clockwise order [(convex hull wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull).

```
# making a lot of points to use predict

new_d <- expand.grid(V1 = seq(-5, 5, 0.01), V2 = seq(-5, 5, 0.01))


# predicting and get inner points

new_tree_p <- predict(Circle_tree, new_d)
new_Tree <- ifelse(new_tree_p >= 0.5, 1, 0)

inner_points_set <- new_d[new_Tree == 0,]


# getting the subset of points which lie on the convex hull

convex_points_set <- inner_points_set[grDevices::chull(inner_points_set$V1, inner_points_set$V2),]

# or if you want to use circle data

inner_points_set2 <- circle[Tree == 0, ]
convex_points_set2 <- inner_points_set2[grDevices::chull(inner_points_set2$V1, inner_points_set2$V2),]


## drawing with geom_polygon()

ggplot(circle, aes(x = V1, y =V2, color = Tree)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2) + 
  geom_polygon(data = convex_points_set, fill = NA, colour = "red") +
  geom_polygon(data = convex_points_set2, fill = NA, colour = "green3") +
  ggtitle("Decision Tree")
```

Comment: Thank You,
Can you explain a bit about grDevices::chull function.

Comment: As you said I was unkind, sorry. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Karan: Have you read the help page and any references therein? ?chull